# How to build dotnetcore project in jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, .net-core, docker-build

Hi I am trying to build dotnetcore project using jenkins. Below is my file structure.

```
locationservices.api
  locationservices.api
  locationservices.api.sln
    Dockerfile
    Jenkinsfile
    locationservices.api.csproj
    startup.cs
    //rest of the files
```

Below is my jenkins file.

```
stage('Build') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk'
          args '-u root:root'
        }
      }

      steps {
        sh 'apt update'
        sh 'apt install -y make'
        sh 'apt install -y apt-transport-https'

        sh 'echo "{\\\"buildNumber\\\":\\\"${BUILD_NUMBER}\\\", \\\"sha\\\":\\\"need to populate\\\"}" > locationservices.api/buildinfo.json'
        sh 'dotnet publish -c Release -o out'
        sh 'chmod a+rw -R .'
        stash name: 'mws-out', includes: 'locationservices.api/out/**'
      }
    }

    stage('Upload to ECR') {
      when {
        branch 'master'
        expression {
          currentBuild.result == null || currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS'
        }
      }

      agent {
        label 'ec2-amazonlinux-v1'
      }

      steps {
        unstash name: 'mws-out'

        script {
          docker.build("location/location-service:v_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", "--build-arg http_proxy=${env.http_proxy} --build-arg https_proxy=${env.https_proxy} .")
          docker.withRegistry('path', "ecr") {
            docker.image("location/location-service:v_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}").push("v_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
            docker.image("location/location-service:v_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}").push("latest")
          }
        }
      }
```

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["locationservices.api.csproj", "locationservices.api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "locationservices.api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/locationservices.api"
RUN dotnet build "locationservices.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "locationservices.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "locationservices.api.dll"]
```

When I run in pipeline I get the below error.

```
Step 6/17 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4cc3caf28136
Step 7/17 : COPY locationservices.api/locationservices.api.csproj locationservices.api/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2ecf1c39cc4a
Step 8/17 : RUN dotnet restore "locationservices.api.csproj"
 ---> Running in ba3d3b8d630a
[91mDid you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "locationservices.api.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 145
```

I am not sure Why I am not able to build my project in jenkins. It fails when restoring. Can someone help me to figure it out the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have .netcore SDK installed on the server where jankins is?

Comment: Hi If sdk is not there is there any other way to create image?

Comment: You can't use restore, build, publish etc. commands without the SDK. I'm unsure whether you need them for creating a Docker image, since I'm unfamiliar with Docker.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the computer/server your Jenkins is running on doesn't have netcore SDK installed, which is needed to build netcore apps.You can find the SDK files [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core).

Comment: Hi I changed to FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk. Now I need sdk in jenkins server or in my dockerfile?

Comment: You need to install the SDK on the machine where you run Jenkins from. If it's your computer, install it there, if it runs on a remote computer, it needs to be installed there.

Comment: I understood now. But is there any way to create image without sdk?

Comment: Well, since the only way to build an dotnetcore app is to use the build command, and you need to create a Docker image of a already built app, I'm pretty sure you have to have the SDK. I could be wrong since I'm unfamiliar with Containers in general, but I'm pretty sure.

Comment: I just checked, and yes, SDK is absolutely necessary. If you open the dockerfile in your app, you'll see it uses commands like dotnet build and publish, and you need the SDK for those.